# Chrome DevTools <body> not showing children

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I noticed this while working an a [project](https://github.com/yazeedb/pokedex). 50% of the time, the `<body>`'s elements don't render in Chrome DevTools. Anyone else experience this issue?

"Inspect element" doesn't work either.

[image]

Comment: Have you tryed to refresh the devTool with "Alt+R" ?

Comment: @Fabio_MO Refresh w/o cache? Yes, CMD + Shift + R on MacBook.